# Arch linux dualboot grub problem

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, grub

I had garuda os installed and i wanted to install new os (exodia) when installing exodia alongside garuda i just noticed that efi partition was 300mb and the manual said it had to be atleast 500mb so i deleted it and created new efi partition (700mb) but after that i don't have garuda in grub. I chrooted into garuda reinstalled kernel and its headers generated grub config and i still can't see garuda in grub os-prober can't see it either. if i run os-prober when im in exodia it doesn't log anything but when i run it when im in chroot it logs only exodia

how can i fix grub so i can boot into garuda, i can only boot to exodia rn

```
nvme0n1     259:0    0   1,8T  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0 830,9G  0 part /var/log
│                                     /var/cache
│                                     /home
│                                     /
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0  31,3G  0 part
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 999,9G  0 part /mnt/var/cache
│                                     /mnt/var/log
│                                     /mnt/home
│                                     /mnt
│                                     /mnt
│                                     /run/media/chara/166c3d34-f77f-4495-9f7a-e374fb014559
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   700M  0 part /mnt/boot/efi
                                      /boot/efi
```

`nvme0n1p1` is exodia
`nvme0n1p3` is garuda